# How can I create a Set of IDs from a list of sObjects?

Tags: map, list, set

To get a set of Ids from a list of Contacts for example, I could:

1. Query for the List of sObjects
2. Create a map from my list using the constructor
3. Use the map.KeySet() method to get my set.

Does anyone know of a more efficient design pattern?

I ultimately want a set to pass off to an @future method.

Comment: You can also consider using the Queueable interface for your use case, which allows passing non-primitive data types to asynchronous methods: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_queueing_jobs.htm

I feel there's a sentiment among the SFDC developer community to stop using @future in favor of Queueable as well.